# Update podcast feed on existing pre-downloaded MP3s

Tags: itunes, mp3, id3

When I used to have a poor internet connection, I found it easier to download the .NET Rocks! podcasts from the [archive on their site](http://www.dotnetrocks.com/archives.aspx) as MP3s, and add them to iTunes (the iTunes podcast automatic downloads had a tendency to bomb out). For them to show up as podcasts, I had to update their info/tags/metadata to have a 'Media Kind' of 'Podcast'.

Since then, I have better internet and am now downloading the podcasts via iTunes. However, I now have two ".NET Rocks!" lists in the podcast - one that is associated to the feed `http://feeds.feedburner.com/dotnetrocks_AAC` and another that isn't (the ones I added manually).

And idea of how can I associate the ones I added manually with the feed? It would be great if I could do this in iTunes, but I don't mind using another tool if iTunes doesn't cater for this.

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I Googled some more, and realised there's actually a couple of ID3 extended tags to use. I downloaded the software [Mp3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/download.html), and noticed there are different extended tags (View > Extended Tags, or <kbd>ALT+T</kbd>) between a podcast that is listed in the list with the feed, and one that I added manually, namely:

1. PODCASTDESC - the description of the episode, e.g. "Carl and Richard talk to Gus Issa..."
2. PODCASTID - the URL to the episode, e.g. http://www.dotnetrocks.com/default.aspx?ShowNum=625
3. PODCASTURL - the URL to the entire podcast series, e.g. http://feeds.feedburner.com/dotnetrocks_AAC

Also, I already had the below:

- PODCAST - the file is a media type of Podcast, i.e. value = 1

Now to find a way to automate the updating of this, have a lot of MP3s!

**Update:** To bulk update the fields in Mp3tag, you can go to Tools > Options, or <kbd>CTRL+O</kbd>, to open the Options dialog. In this, go to Tag Panel in the left pane. Add The above fields (e.g. PODCASTURL) in the Tag Panel list, and click OK. You can then select multiple items in the program, change their values, and press Save to apply the changes. Awesome! Then, delete the podcasts from iTunes, but choose the Keep Files option when asked what to do with the actual files. Then, drag and drop the files to iTunes to re-link it and you should see everything associated with the right podcast :)

Hope this helped someone, cheers,

James

Comment: You might also be able to streamline this with the filename to tag option, I *think* you can feed it a path with folders as variables.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I just updated the PODCASTID to the show prefix and manually updated the numbers in the ID (hope they're right :B). The PODCASTURL is the same so that was easy. The PODCASTDESC I created an action to guess based on an existing tag (COMMENT had this info), and bulk cleared comment. Wasn't tooo much effort, but think it can definitely be streamlined, especially for typists that are slower than me :)